# Ubuntu utility or ruby gem to convert sqlite to CoreData?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, core-data, sqlite, rubygems

I'm developing rails app for mobile devises.
Now I face a problem - how to convert sqlite3 database into CoreData for iOS devises...
My rails app is runnning on Ubuntu server.

Do you now some ubuntu utility or ruby gem, which help me convert sqlite3 database into CoreData database?

Comment: I don't think there is a gem but perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388529/core-data-data-schema-from-existing-sqlite-database) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using SQLite, you're probably better off continuing to use SQLite. In that case there are a couple of convenient Objective-C SQLite wrappers-- [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) and [PLDatabase](https://opensource.plausible.coop/wiki/display/PLDB/PLDatabase). With either (or with SQLite's native API, if you know that) you can just use the SQLite file as is, with no conversion.